# how to link hyperlink show/visible with login status

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

My C# Asp.net master page includes a login control, login status and an hyperlink (named register). When user is login the login status is changed to logout. The hyperlink i mentioned browser a registration page. The problem i am having is that if a user login, still the register hyperlink exists. I want it to hide automatically when a user login. Remember, these three controls are on master page, while i am using multiple child pages. I dont know how to hide the register hyperlink upon user login in child pages. I have searched every corner of google but could not find my answer. even i don't understand what keyword this top should be searched with. If someone know how to handle this issue, kindly tell me. I shall be very thankful for this.

Comment: Excuse me, it seems i have not properly described my problem. if said in short, you may assume that i have a hyperlink to which i want to invisible if someone login. because this hyperlink browse a registration page which i dont want to show to already signed in users

Comment: i am using the following code

Comment: <div id="LoginControl">
    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" 
        FormatString="Welcome {0} |" />
 &nbsp;<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
        LoginText="Sign In" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
        LogoutText="Sign Out" BorderStyle="None" CssClass="logintext" />
    &nbsp;or
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlinkRgstr" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Register.aspx" 
        CssClass="logintext">Register</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;</div>
      
</div>

Comment: @user2599269 Don't ever add code as a comment. It's completely unreadable. You can edit your original question, add, and FORMAT your code there so it's actually readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
   <AnonymousTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server">Register</asp:HyperLink>
      <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" .../>
   </AnonymousTemplate>
   <LoggedInTemplate>
      <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus2" runat="server" .../>
   </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: Hi win, i didn't know before the use of LoginView. Your code seems to be working. My vote is for you answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the login/logout control disappears - trace how it is done and do the same to the register control.

Comment: Yes, ur right. But actually this ready made controls will be very difficult to be traced for a begginer like me. thank you though

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a LoginView control.  It provides a LoggedInTemplate and an AnonymousTemplate.  Put the register link in your AnonymousTemplate and leave the LoggedInTemplate blank.

Comment: Thank you randcd for your answer